# CRUD com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma single-page e preciso salvar o valor de uma variavél no banco de dados.
Como fazer isso usando o angular js?

Essa variavél ela recebe o titulo da minha single-page.
Esse titulo ele será personalizado pelo cliente.

Alguém teria uma dica de como poderia fazer isso apenas usando tecnologias client-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estou estudando exatamente sobre isso estes dias, para isto, dê uma estudada sobre ngResource (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). Você vai precisar de um serviço (como PHP) e um banco de dados (como MySQL) para poder manusear os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente acredito que isto não é possível usando apenas tecnologias *client-side* (usando file:// como repositório) - AngularJS necessitará de URLs válidas.

Estabeleça um serviço HTTP local (NodeJS, IIS e Apache são alguns candidatos) e sirva seus arquivos a partir deles.

Quanto a bancos de dados client-side, uma sugestão é o [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).